# How to delete internal storage file in android?

Tags: android, file-io

I have used the Android internal storage to save a file for my application (using `openFileOutput`) but I would like to delete that file, is it possible and how?

Comment: For kotlin please see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66775979/12272687)

Answer (score 132, accepted):

```
File dir = getFilesDir();
File file = new File(dir, "my_filename");
boolean deleted = file.delete();
```

Comment: what is the rule for my_filename ?

Answer (score 25):

I know this is a bit of an oldie, but the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) say to use:

```
deleteFile("filename");
```

rather than:

```
File.delete();
```

Which if you are already using:

```
getFilesDir();
```

kind of makes sense.

Answer (score 9):

You should always delete files that you no longer need. The most straightforward way to delete a file is to have the opened file reference call delete() on itself.

`myFile.delete()`;

If the file is saved on internal storage, you can also ask the Context to locate and delete a file by calling deleteFile():

`myContext.deleteFile(fileName);`

Note: When the user uninstalls your app, the Android system deletes the following:
All files you saved on internal storage
All files you saved on external storage using `getExternalFilesDir()`.
However, you should manually delete all cached files created with `getCacheDir()` on a regular basis and also regularly delete other files you no longer need.

**Source** : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Answer (score 8):

If you want to delete all files from a folder then use the following function:

```
private void deleteTempFolder(String dir) {
        File myDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"+dir);
        if (myDir.isDirectory()) {
            String[] children = myDir.list();
            for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                new File(myDir, children[i]).delete();
            }
        }
    }
```

Folder must be present on storage. If not we can check one more codition for it.

```
  if (myDir.exists() && myDir.isDirectory()) {
//write same defination for it.
}
```

Comment: This is a very good answer, but if you're like me not seeing anything under myDir.list(), make sure to ask for storage permission real-time! Just how you would ask for any other permission (i.e.: Camera), but pass in "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE".

Answer (score 4):

```
new File(mUri.toString).delete();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 void clearMyFiles() {
    File[] files = context.getFilesDir().listFiles();
    if(files != null)
        for(File file : files) {
           file.delete();
        }
 }
```

Comment: This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content. Suggest adding a description of what it does and how it answers the question.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative in Kotlin

```
val file: File = context.getFileStreamPath("file_name")
val deleted: Boolean = file.delete()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `delete` method of [File](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html)