# Delete file from internal storage

Tags: android, file-io

I'm trying to delete images stored in internal storage. I've come up with this so far:

```
File dir = getFilesDir();
File file = new File(dir, id+".jpg");
boolean deleted = file.delete();
```

And this is from another question, which was [answered with](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3554949/2246344):

```
File dir = getFilesDir();
File file = new File(dir, "my_filename");
boolean deleted = file.delete();
```

My example always returns false. I can see the file `fx 2930.jpg` in DDMS in eclipse.

Answer (score 142, accepted):

The `getFilesDir()` somehow didn't work.
Using a method, which returns the entire path and filename gave the desired result. Here is the code:

```
File file = new File(inputHandle.getImgPath(id));
boolean deleted = file.delete();
```

Comment: Where `inputHandle.getImgPath(id)` is **filePath**

Answer (score 48):

Have you tried [Context.deleteFile()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#deleteFile(java.lang.String)) ?

Comment: Tried a variant with Contex.deletFile(), which didn't work. Below is what seemed to work.

Comment: @user661543 What's full path returned by the ih.getImgPath()? What you'd passed as an argument to delete file? If the method above didn't work then most likely stored your file out of application package. Or you might have passed wrong file name as an argument.

Comment: +1 It's simplest way to remove file written via `new OutputStreamWriter(context.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)).write(data);`

Answer (score 21):

Java

```
File file = new File(photoPath);
file.delete();

MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context,
                new String[]{file.toString()},
                new String[]{file.getName()},null);
```

Kotlin

```
val file = File(photoPath) 
file.delete()

MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, arrayOf(file.toString()),
      arrayOf(file.getName()), null)
```

Answer (score 15):

```
String dir = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
File f0 = new File(dir, "myFile");
boolean d0 = f0.delete(); 
Log.w("Delete Check", "File deleted: " + dir + "/myFile " + d0);
```

The code `File dir = getFilesDir();` doesn't work because this is a request for a File object.
You're trying to retrieve the String that declares the path to your directory, so you need to declare 'dir' as a String, and then request that the directory's absolute path in String form be returned by the constructor that has access to that information.

Answer (score 11):

You can also use: `file.getCanonicalFile().delete();`

Answer (score 4):

```
File file = new File(getFilePath(imageUri.getValue())); 
boolean b = file.delete();
```

is not working in my case.

```
boolean b = file.delete();                 // returns false
boolean b = file.getAbsolutePath.delete(); // returns false
```

always returns false.

The issue has been resolved by using the code below:

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
contentResolver.delete(uriDelete, null, null);
```

Comment: I know i couldn't leave 'thanks' message, but.... i love you so much !!!!! THANKS !

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()`?

Seems you fixed your problem by initializing the File object with a full path.  I believe this would also do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
>     2019-11-12 20:05:50.178 27764-27764/com.strba.myapplicationx I/File: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.strba.myapplicationx/files/Readings/JPEG_20191112_200550_4444350520538787768.jpg//file when it was created

2019-11-12 20:05:58.801 27764-27764/com.strba.myapplicationx I/File: content://com.strba.myapplicationx.fileprovider/my_images/JPEG_20191112_200550_4444350520538787768.jpg //same file when trying to delete it
```

solution1:

```
              Uri uriDelete=Uri.parse (adapter.getNoteAt (viewHolder.getAdapterPosition ()).getImageuri ());//getter getImageuri on my object from adapter that returns String with content uri
```

here I initialize Content resolver
and delete it with a passed parameter of that URI

```
            ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver ();
            contentResolver.delete (uriDelete,null ,null );
```

solution2(my first solution-from head in this time I do know that  ): content resolver exists...

```
              String path = "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.strba.myapplicationx/files/Readings/" +
                    adapter.getNoteAt (viewHolder.getAdapterPosition ()).getImageuri ().substring (58);

            File file = new File (path);
            if (file != null) {
                file.delete ();
            }
```