# android deleting a file from internal storage

Tags: java, android

I have created a file stored on internal storage from an activity. How can I delete this file from another activity?

I'm thinking I'll have to get the file's directory (which I'm not sure how to) and delete it. I tried using

```
context.deleteFile();
```

but it won't work because I'm trying to call it from a non-static method.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Here is your answer :

```
File dir = getFilesDir();
File file = new File(dir, "my_filename");
boolean deleted = file.delete();
```

Comment: Did you tried to use something like this : `context.getFilesDir()+"/pathToMyFile";` instead of using only `getFilesDir()` ?

Comment: Actually, I found a pretty stupid logic error with my code... Now I feel a like dope.

Comment: The important thing is that you found your problem and fixed it : )

Answer (score 3):

You can try getting the instance pointing to the file and deleting it like in 
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486529/android-delete-file-from-internal-storage)
or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486529/android-delete-file-from-internal-storage)