# how can i overwrite a file if it exists in directory

Tags: java, android

i'm saving image in my directory with same name (for a purpose) but when file is already exists there it won't get overwritten , how do i know that ? because when i'm saving this file the already existing file is not changing but when i use a different name for my file it works. so what i want is to replace the existing file with a new one. so far this is what i'm trying :

```
 content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                Bitmap bitmap = content.getDrawingCache(); // an bitmap file for saving


                File file = new File(context.getApplicationContext().getFilesDir() + "/img.jpg"); //here's the path where i'm saving my file

                if (file.exists()){

                    file.delete(); // here i'm checking if file exists and if yes then i'm deleting it but its not working 
                }


                String path = file.getPath();

                try {
                    file.createNewFile();
                    FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, ostream);


                    savedFile = new File(path);


                    ostream.close();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
```

i'm doing another check right after deleting existing file :

```
                if (file.exists()){

                    Toast.makeText(context , "Still EXISTS",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

and this time file is not here cause the toast is not appearing.

Comment: i would love to know the reason of down-votes.

Comment: are you using Android 4.4 or greater?

Comment: it 5.1.0 @ScaryWombat

Comment: more answers = more down votes.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248292/how-to-delete-a-file-from-sd-card

Answer (score 2):

Add this line to Your Code

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(myDir + "/score.jpg", false);
```

Comment: this is for saving characters

Answer (score 2):

First, Let insert the permission in your AndroidManifest.xml file (less than Android 6.0 version)

```
android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Then, use the below code to write the bitmap to file

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
OutputStream fOut = null;
File file = new File(path, "FitnessGirl"+".jpg"); // the File to save to
fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
Bitmap pictureBitmap = content.getDrawingCache();// Your bitmap
//Bitmap pictureBitmap = getImageBitmap(myurl); // obtaining the Bitmap
pictureBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut); // saving the Bitmap to a file compressed as a JPEG with 85% compression rate
fOut.flush();
fOut.close(); // do not forget to close the stream

MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),file.getAbsolutePath(),file.getName(),file.getName());
```

Comment: Just part file. You can delete it. I updated it. Accept it if it is useful

Comment: hey man sorry for responding late , was at work so i tried your code but still effect is same. see my code

Comment: `String path =  CropActivity.this.getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().toString();
                                OutputStream fOut = null;
                                File file = new File(path, "img"+".jpg");
                    savedFile = file;
                                try {
                                    fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }`

Comment: `Bitmap pictureBitmap = content.getDrawingCache();
pictureBitmap = getImageBitmap(myurl); 
                                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut);     
                                    fOut.flush();
                                
                                try {
                                    fOut.close(); 
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }`

Comment: `try {
                                    MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),file.getAbsolutePath(),file.getName(),file.getName());
                                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                    Log.d("saved",""+savedFile.toString());`

Comment: the file is being saved at the same place but still no change in the file.

Comment: I think first you have to delete the file first. Ref :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486529/delete-file-from-internal-storage

Comment: this is how i'm deleting file :  `File alreadyStoredFile = new File(CropActivity.this.getApplicationContext().getFilesDir() + "/img"+".jpg");
                    Log.d("TG",""+alreadyStoredFile);
                    alreadyStoredFile.deleteOnExit();

                    Log.d("bool",""+alreadyStoredFile.exists());`

Comment: and after that i'm doing the saving thing.. , but still same behavior exists.

Comment: OK. Let add one more permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`  . Then try to make a new image, if it is successful, then call delete function. If the step is also successful, then finally you can call delete+create new image

Comment: **FALSE AND MISLEADING** - there is no such permission as android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
boolean result = Files.deleteIfExists(file.toPath());
```

Also make sure you have write permission enabled!

**PS:** From Android Lollipop you need the [runtime permission](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) and the permission already set in manifest file won't work.

Comment: Oops, Now you will start getting downvotes and close requests ;)

Comment: @Prokash   `runtime permission` this could be the reason , any guidance how can i prompt that permission request ??

Comment: @remy boys Please check the link on my answer. I had the exact same problem.