# how to delete a file from android studio code

Tags: android, file, path

I create and manage file from android application with this code but what I want then its to delete it.

This is the code how I write and read it:

```
 private String readDataFromString()
{
    try{
        FileInputStream fis = this.openFileInput("encryptedNotePad.txt");
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);

        char[] inputBuffer = new char[100];
        String s = "";

        int charRead;
        while((charRead = isr.read(inputBuffer)) > 0){
            // Convertimos los char a String
            String readString = String.copyValueOf(inputBuffer, 0, charRead);
            s += readString;

            inputBuffer = new char[100];
        }

        isr.close();
        return s;

    }catch (IOException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}


private void writeDataToString (String data) throws FileNotFoundException {
    try{
        //FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("encryptedNotePad.txt", MODE_PRIVATE);
        FileOutputStream fos = this.openFileOutput("encryptedNotePad.txt", MODE_PRIVATE);
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);

        // Escribimos el String en el archivo
        osw.write(data);
        osw.flush();
        osw.close();

    }catch (IOException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

How Can I delete it?

I found this:

```
File file = new File(selectedFilePath);
boolean deleted = file.delete();
```

But, I dont know the file path.Whats the file path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But, I dont know the file path.Whats the file path?

Path means **the file's path** where you can get access to it or doing stuff on it.

I believe in your case, it will be:

```
encryptedNotePad.txt
```

Like you used it already:

```
FileOutputStream fos = this.openFileOutput("encryptedNotePad.txt", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

So if you give the path to the following code, it should work fine I hope:

```
File file = new File("encryptedNotePad.txt");
boolean deleted = file.delete();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I use this code but the file isnt delete:   File file = new File(file_name+".txt");
            if(file.exists() && !file.isDirectory())
            { // call delete method
                boolean success = file.delete();
                if (success)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "File was deleted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

Comment: Any errors do you see? Perhaps the path which you're trying to delete that file doesn't have the right permission?

Comment: Hello. Thats the problem, I dont get any error message, it just pass without delete that. For that I set up that toast message to check this out. I set up READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in manifest. But regarding the file path, I dont know what to do because I open it with "FileOutputStream fos = this.openFileOutput("encryptedNotePad.txt", MODE_PRIVATE);
" and when I try to delete it with File file = new File("encryptedNotePad.txt");
boolean deleted = file.delete();, but deleted is false. There is another way to delete a file? or what Im doing wrong?

Comment: You missed a parameter I guess. Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24857764/4409113