# Android - How can I delete downloaded zip file?

Tags: android

After downloaded the zip file
I unzip it, and take it file and use it.
but now, 
How can I delete the downloaded zip file?

Comment: What version of android? Are you writing a program to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to delete internal storage file in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554722/how-to-delete-internal-storage-file-in-android)

Comment: @KaliforniaDreaming It isn't possible to "un-flag" a post.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Questions here should __show research effort or attempts__. Please take a __[tour]__.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the `delete()` method in your `File`. Like this:

```
File file = new File(filePath);  
boolean deleted = file.delete();
```

`filePath` is a `String` containing the path to your zip file.

Do not forget to check if deleted is true. It is true if the file was successfully deleted.