# Deleting file from internal storage

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

How do I delete a file or folder on the internal storage in android with Delphi for android

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use the [`TFile`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.IOUtils.TFile) and [`TDirectory`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.IOUtils.TDirectory) classes in the [`System.IOUtils`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.IOUtils) unit.

For example:

```
TDirectory.Delete(<YOUR DIR PATH>);
```

or

```
TFile.Delete(<YOUR FILE PATH>);
```

Look in Embarcadero's documentation to get the right path of your files and folders on the various platforms:

[Standard RTL Path Functions across the Supported Target Platforms](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Standard_RTL_Path_Functions_across_the_Supported_Target_Platforms)

Answer (score 1):

Referred from :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27047502/5193608
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3554949/5193608

Main Part from both links:

You should always delete files that you no longer need. The most straightforward way to delete a file is to have the opened file reference call delete() on itself.

```
myFile.delete();
```

If the file is saved on internal storage, you can also ask the Context to locate and delete a file by calling deleteFile():

```
myContext.deleteFile(fileName);
```

Note: When the user uninstalls your app, the Android system deletes the following: All files you saved on internal storage All files you saved on external storage using getExternalFilesDir(). However, you should manually delete all cached files created with getCacheDir() on a regular basis and also regularly delete other files you no longer need.

Source : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Directly you can do is :

```
File dir = getFilesDir();
File file = new File(dir, "my_filename");
boolean deleted = file.delete();
```

Hope,it helps!

Comment: OP uses Delphi, not Java :)