# How to delete file in android?

Tags: java, android

I have used the android internal storage to save a file for my application.

**`Ex`**

```
File rootFolder = context.getFilesDir();
File albumIdFolder = new File(rootFolder,getAlbumId());
```

Basicaly i want to delete the folder

So i tried with

```
 File rootFolder = context.getFilesDir();
 File albumIdFolder = new File(rootFolder,getAlbumId());
 albumIdFolder.delete()
```

but this not working not deleting folder

I readed this answares but not worked in my case please help me solve this issue i am not getting where i am going wong.

[Delete file from internal storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486529/delete-file-from-internal-storage)

[How to delete internal storage file in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554722/how-to-delete-internal-storage-file-in-android)

**Edit 2**

**`Ex`** ^(folder hierarchy)

```
data
    user
        0
         packageName
                    files
                        155775346846131
                                       otherData
```

i want to delete `155775346846131` folder

Comment: @A.Najafi sir i know it releted to this question but this solution not worked for me

Comment: You need to delete all files in the folder before you can delete the folder. You can only delete empty folders.

Comment: if you have files in your folder then first delete files then delete folder/directory

Comment: @ApploneInfotech: check [How to delete a whole folder and content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943629/how-to-delete-a-whole-folder-and-content)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete a whole folder and content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943629/how-to-delete-a-whole-folder-and-content)

Comment: @AnasMehar if we remove parent directory it will not work ?

Comment: @ApploneInfotech no it's not work you must delete its child/files first.

Comment: @AnasMehar but why this will not work can you explain

Comment: @ApploneInfotech Because android have linux kernel so in linux you must delete child before dir

Comment: @AnasMehar can u provide answare with discription i will accept it thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can delete files with folder like as below,

```
void deleteFiles(Context context) {
    File rootFolder = context.getFilesDir();
    File fileDir = new File( rootFolder,getAlbumId());
    if (fileDir.exists()) {
        File[] listFiles = fileDir.listFiles();
        for (File listFile : listFiles) {
        if (!listFile.delete()) {
            System.err.println( "Unable to delete file: " + listFile );
        }
        }
    }
    rootFolder.delete();
}
```

Source : [How to delete a whole folder and content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943629/how-to-delete-a-whole-folder-and-content)

Don't forgot to give Storage permission.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete files and folders recursively like this:

```
public void deleteFolderRecursive(File fileOrDirectory) {

   if (fileOrDirectory.isDirectory()) {
   for (File child : fileOrDirectory.listFiles()) {
      deleteFolderRecursive(child);
   }
}

 fileOrDirectory.delete();
}
```